# How to delete an element from array in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, splice

I have two functions , one of them adds an item in array and the other one delete from that array using React JS (hooks).[Both are handler of click event].
What I have works incorrectly.

``id`` comes from ``contact.length`` and I deleted it with``contacts.splice(id, 1)``.
I dont have any idea why it has this problem.
it doesnt delete what would be clicked but a random one.

```
function handleAddRecord(nameValue, phoneValue) {
        setContacts([...contacts , {
            id : contacts.length,
            name : nameValue,
            phone : phoneValue
        }])
    }
    

    function handleDelete(id) {
        console.log("manager", id);
        const newContacts =  contacts.splice([id],1);
        setContacts([...newContacts]);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to delete a specific value from array ? If yes then use array.indexOf() and then use array.splice()

Comment: Please add the code where you are calling *handleDelete* function

Comment: I think it should be `contacts.splice(id - 1, 1)`

Comment: @Mr_Green it cant be as it's just removing the last one so he might use just .pop()

Comment: @Sanmeet hmm I thought the same but checking again seems that is not the case. I think the below answers are correct but the id should be `id - 1`, IMO.

Comment: Thank you all guys i have tested both `contacts.splice(id - 1, 1)` and array,indexOf()
none of them was useful to me this way

Comment: @MojtabaSedighi Can you add the code where you are calling the *handleDelete* function??

Comment: no its not possible.
You have any idea related to that? @NeERAJ TK

Comment: @MojtabaSedighi EDIT the question and add the code at bottom !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the issue on the implementation is **id** generation keeping it array length could lead to issue as you delete and add elements there could be scenarios where there is same id for multiple items.

One of most widely used generator is **uuid** https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Usage

```
const uuid = require("uuid");
uuid.v4(); // ⇨ '9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d'
```

Now use this in your implementation

**Add Operation:**

```
const handleAddRecord = (nameValue, phoneValue) => {
  const newRecord = {
    id: uuid.v4(),  // This should be unique at all times
    name: nameValue,
    phone: phoneValue,
  };
  setContacts([...contacts, newRecord]);
};
```

**Delete Operation:**

Use **filter** rather than **splice** as for splice you'll need to find the index of the element with id. But with **Filter** it can be done is a single line

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
  setContacts(contacts.filter(item => item.id !== id));
};
```

Comment: I think you'll remove everything but the element actually useless.

Comment: Sorry just Updated the answer use this setContacts(contacts.filter(item => item.id !== id));

Comment: @MojtabaSedighi try the updated one on the answer. that works

Comment: thanka alot @samridhgupta it works as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Here we're assuming that `id` is the index of the element to be removed.

The `splice` function returns the removed elements, thus is not useful to take its result. Instead, make a copy of the array first, then remove the undesired element:

```
function handleDelete(id) {
    console.log("manager", id);
    const newContacts =  [...contacts];
    newContacts.splice(id,1);
    setContacts(newContacts);
}
```

That's because `splice` alters the array itself.

More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Thanks for your help,
it works but , 
 When I start clicking delete from the first element from the top it works correct.
and when I click random it has some problem for example it wouldnt be deleted or delete an other one but not which was clicked.

Comment: I think the problem is about how the "id" is chosen. Using the array length is not a reliable reference, and you should have a unique key to assign to every single element. Move to a progressive counter, or better to a pseudo-random id generator like this one: https://github.com/dylang/shortid

Comment: Thank you alot for your help 
I did use ' uuid' as it mentioned here
and my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Ok, id return index of current map?
Follow this example:

```js
const assoc = [...contacts];
assoc.splice(id, 1);
setContacts(assoc);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,
it works but , 
 When I start clicking delete from the first element from the top it works correct.
and when I click random it has some problem for example it wouldnt be deleted or delete an other one but not which was clicked.

Comment: I can undestand with life cycle components, whrn yout use map every time use a key props, and, whrn you use pro index... result delete another component.. I will public 2 ways how to use here

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the item by finding its index from array.

For Example:

```
function handleDelete(id) {
   console.log("manager", id);
   const index = contacts.findIndex((x) => x.id === id);
   const newContacts = [
      ...contacts.splice(0, index),
      ...contacts.splice(index + 1),
   ];
   setContacts(newContacts);
}
```

Comment: I think you'll remove everything but the element actually useless.

Answer (score 0):

You need undestand, every time when i'll remove a item from a array of a index, that this index has use unique key... When React remove a item 6 (a example) this is remove of array first, and when react re-render function react can delete another component, because a array exist key 6, wehn you have more 6 item from array... Understand?

Follow a example:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function User(data) { // data is a array

  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(data); // data return a list of contacts

  /* contacts result a array object and has the following attributes 
    [{
      name: 'Cael',
      tel_number: '+55 11 9999-999',
      e_mail: 'user@example.com',
  !   moment: "2021-06-15T05:09:42.475Z" // see this a date in ISO string
    }]
  */

  // about moment atribute:
  // this atribute result when use `new Date().toISOString()`
  // and this value is added in the moment that create a object in array list
  // It's mean that every time result a unique key

  const deleteFn = (val) => { // val result index of component and item array
    const assoc = [...contacts];
    assoc.splice(val, 1);
    setContacts(assoc);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {!!contacts.length &&
      contacts.map((assoc, i) => { // variable i result in your id
        const { moment, name, e_mail, tel_number } = assoc; // moment use a unique key
        return (
          <li key={moment}> 
            <span>{name}</span>
            <span>{e_mail}</span>
            <span>{tel_number}</span>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => deleteFn(i)}>Delete</button>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default User;
```

I hope, this helpfull you!