# How to set properly the filtered new list to the set State using react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have big problem pertaining removing the filtered clicked index [MY LAST THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68003583/how-to-find-the-state-index-and-do-the-process-of-splicing-the-data?noredirect=1#comment120196349_68003583). I create a thread here in stackoverflow last an hour ago regarding how to remove the filter index, in result yes it is working well now. Right now I hold the result of new list, my problem when I set the newList to the setState it is weird happened the last index is removed I don't know what's happen to my setState.

**Tech Used:
Ant design, React Js, Redux**

**Preview of my work:**

[image: my work]

**Here is the whole code of my function:**

```
    const ReceivedCheckModalInsert = () => {

    
    const list_bank =  useSelector((state) => state.receive_checks.list_banks.data);
    const list_remarks =  useSelector((state) => state.receive_checks.list_remarks.data);
    const list_bank_accounts =  useSelector((state) => state.receive_checks.list_bank_accounts.data);
    const list_customer_payor =  useSelector((state) => state.receive_checks.list_customer_payor.data);

    

    const AddInitialData = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setStateInitialData([...stateInitialData, 
            {
                customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
                bank: list_bank,
                bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
                check_no: null,
                check_date: null,
                amount: null,
                remarks: list_remarks,
            },
            {
                customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
                bank: list_bank,
                bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
                check_no: null,
                check_date: null,
                amount: null,
                remarks: list_remarks,
            },
            {
                customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
                bank: list_bank,
                bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
                check_no: null,
                check_date: null,
                amount: null,
                remarks: list_remarks,
            },
            {
                customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
                bank: list_bank,
                bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
                check_no: null,
                check_date: null,
                amount: null,
                remarks: list_remarks,
            },
            {
                customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
                bank: list_bank,
                bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
                check_no: null,
                check_date: null,
                amount: null,
                remarks: list_remarks,
            },
        ])
    }

    const initialData = [
        {
            customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
            bank: list_bank,
            bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
            check_no: null,
            check_date: null,
            amount: null,
            remarks: list_remarks,
        },
        {
            customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
            bank: list_bank,
            bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
            check_no: 2323,
            check_date: null,
            amount: null,
            remarks: list_remarks,
        },
        {
            customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
            bank: list_bank,
            bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
            check_no: null,
            check_date: null,
            amount: null,
            remarks: list_remarks,
        },
        {
            customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
            bank: list_bank,
            bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
            check_no: null,
            check_date: null,
            amount: null,
            remarks: list_remarks,
        },
        {
            customer_payor: list_customer_payor,
            bank: list_bank,
            bank_branch: list_bank_accounts,
            check_no: null,
            check_date: null,
            amount: null,
            remarks: list_remarks,
        }
    ] 

    const [stateInitialData, setStateInitialData] = useState(initialData);

    const RemoveEachRow = (e,indexClicked) => {

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("--------------",indexClicked)

        console.log(stateInitialData,"Initial Data");

        const newList = stateInitialData.filter((item,index) => index != indexClicked);

        console.log(newList);

        console.log("-------","HERE IS WORKING WELL FILTERING THE INDEX");

        console.log("------", "lets set state")
        
        setStateInitialData(newList);

        console.log("------", "after i setState the new list my setState is not correct because I don't know why the last index setted there on my useState")

    }

    return(
        <div>
            <Modal title="Add Received Checks"
                width={1600}
                visible={isModalVisibleInsert}
                footer={[
                    <Button className="btn-pink"
                        key="add_initial_data"
                        onClick={(e) => AddInitialData(e)}
                        style={{width: '120px',marginRight:30}}>
                      Add Row
                    </Button>,
                    <Button className="btn-pink"
                        key="save_changes"
                        onClick={handleOk}
                        style={{width: '120px'}}>
                      Save Changes
                    </Button>,
                    <Button className="btn-pink"
                        key="clear"
                        onClick={() => {
                            form.resetFields();
                        }}>
                      Clear
                    </Button>,
                    <Button
                      key="close"
                      className="btn-pink"
                      onClick={handleCancelInsert}
                    >
                      Close
                    </Button>,
                ]}
                onOk={handleOk}
                onCancel={handleCancelInsert}
            >
            <Button className="btn-pink" style={{width: '115px'}}>{moment().format("MMMM DD, YYYY")}</Button>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <form className="form-horizontal"  autoComplete="off">
            <table className="table  table-fixed table-hover table-striped bankaccount " style={{ width: "100%", zIndex: "-9" }}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>CUSTOMER / PAYOR</th>
                        <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>BANK</th>
                        <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>BRANCH</th>
                        <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>CHECK NO</th>
                        <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>CHECK DATE</th>
                        <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>AMOUNT</th>
                        <th style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: '400' }}>REMARKS</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {
                    stateInitialData.map((data, index) => {
                        
                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <span>
                                        <select className="browser-default custom-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                            <option selected>Select Customer</option>
                                            {
                                                data.customer_payor.map((customer_payor_data) => {
                                                    return (
                                                        <>
                                                            <option value={customer_payor_data.id}>{customer_payor_data.type == '1' ? 
                                                            customer_payor_data.company_name  + ' / ' +  customer_payor_data.contact_person : (customer_payor_data.payer)}</option>
                                                        </>
                                                    )
                                                })
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span>
                                        <select className="browser-default custom-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                            <option selected>Select Bank</option>
                                            {
                                                data.bank.map((bank_data) => {
                                                    return (
                                                        <>
                                                            <option value={bank_data.id}>{bank_data.bank_name}</option>
                                                        </>
                                                    )
                                                })
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span>
                                        <select className="browser-default custom-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                            <option selected>Select Branch</option>
                                            {
                                                data.bank_branch.map((bank_branch_data) => {
                                                    return (
                                                        <>
                                                            <option value={bank_branch_data.branch}>{bank_branch_data.branch}</option>
                                                        </>
                                                    )
                                                })
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span>
                                        <input className='form-control' type='text'/>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span>
                                        <input type="date" className="form-control"/>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span>
                                        <input className='form-control' type='text'/>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span>
                                        <select className="browser-default custom-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                        <option selected>Select Remarks</option>
                                        {
                                            data.remarks.map((remarks_data) => {
                                                return (
                                                    <>
                                                        <option value={remarks_data.check_remark}>{remarks_data.check_remark}</option>
                                                    </>
                                                )
                                            })
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td style={{backgroundColor:'#FFFF',borderTopColor:'#FFFF'}}><DeleteOutlined onClick={(e) => RemoveEachRow(e,index)}/></td>
                            </tr>
                        )

                        
                    })  
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </form>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
};
```

**Here is code of remove each row:**

```
const RemoveEachRow = (e,indexClicked) => {

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("--------------",indexClicked)

        console.log(stateInitialData,"Initial Data");

        const newList = stateInitialData.filter((item,index) => index != indexClicked);

        console.log(newList);

        console.log("-------","HERE IS WORKING WELL FILTERING THE INDEX");

        console.log("------", "lets set state")
        
        setStateInitialData(newList);

        console.log("------", "after i setState the new list my setState is not correct because I don't know why the last index setted there on my useState")

    }
```

Here is the clicked button:

```
 <td style={{backgroundColor:'#FFFF',borderTopColor:'#FFFF'}}><DeleteOutlined onClick={(e) => RemoveEachRow(e,index)}/></td>
```

Summary: I have default 5 index. On each index there is delete button where this button used to delete each row. as you can see on the image I clicked the highlighted row but the set new list is removed the last index and that is bad behaviour of filtering the data. I don't know where the problem is happened, my thinking the main source of problem is on my setState.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no found key props in yout component, your problem is life cycle... look this: [How to delete an element from array in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67979861/how-to-delete-an-element-from-array-in-react/67980459#67980459)

If this is helpful for you, don't forget to vote.

Comment: I don't forget my key. please see my button. there is index.

Answer (score 0):

See a correctly example:

```js
stateInitialData.map((data, index) => {

    return (
      <tr key={index}> {/* ✅ your map component carry index in the first element */}
        <td>
          <span>
            <select className="browser-default custom-select" aria-label="Default select example">
              <option selected>Select Customer</option>
              {
                data.customer_payor.map((customer_payor_data) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <option value={customer_payor_data.id}>{customer_payor_data.type == '1' ?
                        customer_payor_data.company_name + ' / ' + customer_payor_data.contact_person : (customer_payor_data.payer)}</option>
                    </>
                  )
                })
              }
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>
            <select className="browser-default custom-select" aria-label="Default select example">
              <option selected>Select Bank</option>
              {
                data.bank.map((bank_data) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <option value={bank_data.id}>{bank_data.bank_name}</option>
                    </>
                  )
                })
              }
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>
            <select className="browser-default custom-select" aria-label="Default select example">
              <option selected>Select Branch</option>
              {
                data.bank_branch.map((bank_branch_data) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <option value={bank_branch_data.branch}>{bank_branch_data.branch}</option>
                    </>
                  )
                })
              }
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>
            <input className='form-control' type='text' />
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>
            <input type="date" className="form-control" />
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>
            <input className='form-control' type='text' />
          </span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>
            <select className="browser-default custom-select" aria-label="Default select example">
              <option selected>Select Remarks</option>
              {
                data.remarks.map((remarks_data) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <option value={remarks_data.check_remark}>{remarks_data.check_remark}</option>
                    </>
                  )
                })
              }
            </select>
          </span>
        </td>
        <td style={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFF', borderTopColor: '#FFFF' }}><DeleteOutlined onClick={(e) => RemoveEachRow(e, index)} /></td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
```

When you use the index on the first element, you are talking to React, remove this element.
Ok, now I can use this index in aout delete function:

```js
 const RemoveEachRow = (e,indexClicked) => {
    const assoc = [...stateInitialData];
    assoc.splice(indexClicked, 1);
    setStateInitialData(assoc);
  }
```